# Using the value of a variable defined in NED file in omnetpp.ini file

Tags: omnet++

I want to use "numHosts" variable value in the second command [output-scalar-file] in omnetpp.ini by referring the "numHosts" variable defined in NED file.

```
*.numHosts = 4
output-scalar-file = ${resultdir}/${configname}-h${par("numHosts").strValue}.sca
```

But this error is generated in simulation running phase:

```
Scenario generator: Missing '=' after '${varname' at output-scalar-file=${resultdir}/${configname}-h${par("numHosts").strValue}.sca
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One cannot use NED parameters in an ini file. However, iteration variables may be used. Therefore in order to achieve your goal you can create and use a "temporary" iteration variable:

```
*.numHosts = ${nh=4}
output-scalar-file = ${resultdir}/${configname}-${iterationvarsf}.sca
```

It generates the following file:

```
General-nh=4-.sca
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jerzy D., I can't the relation between the ${nh=4} and the "output-scalar-file = ${resultdir}/${configname}-${iterationvarsf}.sca", because the "nh" variable is not used in this instruction. How it generates "General-nh=4-.sca"?

Comment: Take a look at the list of [predefined variables](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:config-options:predefined-variables). It states that `${iterationvarsf}` is expanded as a list of all iteration variables with their values. Any variable defined in an ini file is treated as iteration variable. As a consequence, in the line `*.numHosts = ${nh=4}` `nh` becomes an iteration variable.